# Mysql select query with temp table

Tags: mysql, select

I want to get all child from my table of specified parent. for this i am using following code but i am getting error.

I have tried same code in sql by using 'with' clause but as in mysql we cant use 'with' clause so i am using this. I found this form [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46061/mysql-equivalent-of-with-in-oracle).

Here is my code

```
 Select Ct.* from 
(Select * from data where parent_id=1
    Union All 
    Select T.* From data T Join  CT on T.parent_id=CT.id
) CT
```

And i am getting this error

```
46 - Table 'db_wtg.ct' doesn't exist
```

Please help me.

Comment: You can't refer to resultset of the subquery from subquery itself.

Comment: then how can i do this? i have no idea...please suggest

Comment: You can either restructure the data or write a stored procedure.  MySQL has basically no support for recursive or hierarchical queries.

Comment: ok....but i have no idea about recursive store procedure for this...can you please help me by providing code?

Comment: Check these http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ , http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/

Comment: ok for now i have solved this in this manner...i get all data inside an array and then i use recursive array to get my result

Comment: looking for a better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using MySQL. If that is the case, MySQL table names are case sensitive. You are creating your temp table as "CT" and trying to select from a table "Ct" that doesn't exist.

Comment: That's not the actual cause of OP problem. The real cause is MySQL not supporting recursive queries.

Comment: I did miss the recursive query in there. That won't fly either.